# RabbitMQ - Certificate Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, rabbitmq, ssl-certificate

I have written a client / server apps on .Net which authenticate against RabbitMQ using username/password/server.

Our security team suggested to change this to certificate authentication.  I have searched RabbitMQ site and on forums but could not locate a solution.

How do I install, configure certificates in .Net Client and Server components (and/or machines) for authentication? What are the parameters needed to create connection in this scenario? Can any one please point to the right resource of example, if any? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

## On the broker side

The RabbitMQ server is provided with **a plugin called rabbitmq-auth-mechanism-ssl** which allows you to authenticate users based on client certificates. I consider that the broker is already configured to accept TLS connections. If it's not the case already, you should follow the [documentation about TLS](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html) on RabbitMQ website.

To configure the plugin, there are two steps you must follow:

1. You need to enable the plugin:

   ```
   rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl
   ```
2. You need to add the new authentication method to the the accepted methods in the broker's configuration file (usually `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf` on Unix for instance). See the [`rabbitmq-auth-mechanism-ssl's`README.md`](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-auth-mechanism-ssl/blob/master/README.md) for some examples.

When this is done, you need to restart the broker for the new configuration to be active.

## On the client side

The documentation about TLS I mentionned above gives examples for several client libraries, including the .NET one. You will find source codes and commands.

Comment: do we need to install the same certificate on every client that we install our .Net component?

Comment: @techspider: It really depends on how you want to isolate each client instance. If you would use the same username/password for all clients, then you would use one certificate for all clients. On the contrary, if you feel it is better for each client to have its own username/password, then the same applies to certificates. The reasoning in the same.

Comment: @Jean-SébastienPédronI have followed the document and get it to work on the server. (server + client both on localhost) but moment I try to run the code from the client side, or, run the command from the server while giving it the host = <ip> instead of "localhost" it throws an error ```ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: IP address mismatch, certificate is not valid for '10.154.0.27'. (_ssl.c:1056)```