# certificate based authentication in rabbitmq-management plugin

Tags: authentication, rabbitmq, sasl

rabbitmq supports certificate based authentication using the rabbitmq-auth-mechanism-ssl plugin (https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-auth-mechanism-ssl/blob/rabbitmq_v3_6_9/README.md). I was able to get the password-less authentication working for the AMQP protocol using this plugin.

However, I could not get the same certificate based (password-less) authentication working for the rabbitmq-management plugin that uses HTTP (for web UI). From the documentation it is not clear if this is supported.

Does rabbitmq-management support the cert based authentication ? If yes, please share the relevant links.

Answer (score -1):

Found this site - it looks legitimate, but I haven't tried it yet myself.

http://www.gettingcirrius.com/2013/01/securing-rabbitmq-management-console.html

Quoting from the link:

> 1. Edit the `rabbitmq.config` file in the `/etc/rabbitmq` director.
> 2. Add a configuration entry:
>
>    ```
>    [{listener, 
>    [{port, 15672},
>     {ssl, true},
>     {ssl_opts, 
>       [{cacertfile, "/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/ca/cacert.pem"},
>        {certfile,   "/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/server/{hostname}.cert.pem"},
>        {keyfile,    "/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/server/{hostname}.key.pem"}]}
>     ]}
>    ]}
>    ].
>    ```
> 3. Restart RabbitMQ.
>
>    ```
>    sudo service rabbitmq-server start
>    ```

Comment: Thaks for sharing the link @Rumesh Eranga, shall verify it

Comment: In my experience, this asks for the client certificate when connecting, but still prompts for a login / password.

Comment: This setup is for TLS / SSL connections and not TLS / SSL Authentication. Authentication requires an additional plug in. This article discusses the setup of TLS / SSL Authentication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066954/rabbitmq-certificate-authentication